# How to read the csv file in controller in Magento-2?

Tags: php, magento2.2

I want to read the **CSV** file for stock update.

My **CSV** file contains :`sku ,qty`.

How to read these values?

If anyone knows please explain it to me.

Comment: For uploading product magento it's own self provides csv upload. Whay do you want to read this?

Answer (score 2):

> Try this

```
protected $csvProcessor;

public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csvProcessor
)
{
     $this->csvProcessor = $csvProcessor;
}
public function readCsvFile($file)
{
     if (!isset($file['tmp_name'])) {
         throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Invalid file upload attempt.'));
     }
     $importProductRawData = $this->csvProcessor->getData($file['tmp_name']);

     foreach ($importProductRawData as $rowIndex => $dataRow) {
         \Zend_Debug::dump($dataRow);
     }
     die();
}
}
```

Comment: But,it is not working..

Comment: which issue you are facing?

Comment: not getting file